# Deselect radio and undo animation

Tags: jquery

I have 2 radio buttons, the "yes" button initiates a rotation of the "speedometer" and I want to basically undo what the "yes" button did if they decide to press "No" after the fact. I can't quite figure out the best way to go about this.

I am trying to do this with this code, and it won't initiate the custom event:

```
jQuery('input[value="Yes"]').bind('click', function(){
       jQuery('input[name="' + jQuery(this).attr('name') + '"]').not(jQuery(this)).trigger('deselect');});
       jQuery('input[value="yes"]').bind('deselect', function(){
             jQuery('#progress').animate(
            {
                marginBottom: '-=5'
            },{
                step: function(now, fx) {
                    jQuery(this).css({transform: 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)'});
            }
}); });
```

here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/pTkkS/12/

Comment: Do you want to uncheck all of the 'Test' radio buttons?

Comment: The test buttons aren't really a part of it just the two groups of 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
    $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
        var marginBottom = $("input[type=radio][value=yes]:checked").length * yourConstantForAnimate;
    });
```

Comment: Are you trying to alter the margin dynamically?

Comment: I tried using this and all I got was can't call length of object [object Object] but i thought it was a good idea

Comment: I didn't have the time to test it against your code. I think what you're looking for is a refined approach to this code if you want to adjust your speedometer dynamically on the fly.